# Acessing $this from within an eloquent relationship

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.1

I have a property model that looks something like this:

```
class Property extends Model
{
    public function accessUsers()
    {
        $access_id = $this->access_id

        return $this->hasMany('App\User')
            ->whereHas('access', function ($query) use ($access_id) {
                $query->where('id', $access_id);
            });
    }
}
```

To be clear: A `Property` has many `User`s. `User`s has a relationship to a model called `Access`. This query should only result with users who have a reltionship with `Access` where `Access.id` is equal to `Property.access_id`

The problem I'm running into is when `$this->access_id` is called it's returning a null value (even when a value exists). `dd($this)` returns a `Property` object but with the attributes all empty. I'm inclined to belive that at this point of the code Eloquent/QueryBuilder hasn't queried the DB to retrieve the attribute values yet.

Is it possible to pull in the values at this point? Can I structure this in a different way that will give me the same results? I'd like to eager load these `accessUsers()` from a controller like so: `Property::with('accessUsers')->get()`

Comment: Can you show your table schema?

Comment: What is the relationship between `User` and `Access`?

Comment: @Xecure did you find a solution for this?

Comment: @FranciscoCaviano sorry I have not. I resorted to write a raw query via `DB::statement()`